# How to make particles emit from certain parts of a 3D object?

Tags: animation, objects, particles

I made a spaceship with animation and I want the particles to come out from only the thrusters but it's coming out from all over the spaceship!

[image]

Comment: Have you used a vertex group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]Use Vertex Groups.

In edit mode
Use Vertex Groups in the Particle System Settings ... Sub Panel Vertex Groups.

- In [edit mode] a vertex group was created
- The same group was used in the Particles System Panel ...  Density.
- Quick Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzRS2cCiBnc

Comment: I appreciate that alot this helped me and now I can carry on. th*nks for the explicit help It was rich and detailed :)

Comment: If you feel this answer is correct please mark it so.  Otherwise please downvote.